# Pandas: Replace values in column based on a match in a different column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, replace

I'm resetting the question to make it clearer to everyone regarding the DataFrame I have issues with. The DataFrame contains over 100,000 rows with over 10 columns. The important issue I have is filling in any values in the `id` column that previously matches some value in `type` column. The values in the `id` column are not unique. Sometimes both `id` and `type` values are NIL.

Note: The order of things should must not be impacted as the records are dated with other columns. There are also no empty cells, all empty cells are filled with "NIL".

***GOAL: To replace as many "NIL" as possible in the `id` column only. I do not care for any "NIL" values in the `type` column. But everything else must remain the same.***

I am assuming this can be done without loops. Thank you for your help! Really appreciate it, strangers!

***Current DataFrame***

| COL1 | id | type | COL4 | COL5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NIL | 123 | moving | NIL | NIL |
| ... | 123 | lend | ... | ... |
| NIL | 456 | penny | ... | NIL |
| ... | NIL | appendix | NIL | ... |
| ... | 251 | appendix | ... | ... |
| NIL | NIL | lend | ... | NIL |
| ... | 665 | NIL | NIL | ... |
| ... | NIL | NIL | ... | ... |
| ... | 251 | retailer | NIL | NIL |
| NIL | 251 | appendix | ... | NIL |
| NIL | 456 | NIL | ... | NIL |

***Expected DataFrame***

| COL1 | id | type | COL4 | COL5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NIL | 123 | moving | NIL | NIL |
| ... | 123 | lend | ... | ... |
| NIL | 456 | penny | ... | NIL |
| ... | ***251*** | appendix | NIL | ... |
| ... | 251 | appendix | ... | ... |
| NIL | ***123*** | lend | ... | NIL |
| ... | 665 | NIL | NIL | ... |
| ... | NIL | NIL | ... | ... |
| ... | 251 | retailer | NIL | NIL |
| NIL | 251 | appendix | ... | NIL |
| NIL | 456 | NIL | ... | NIL |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a merge

```
# assemble the dataframe
In [4]: a
Out[4]: 
[26235,
 'fruit',
 26235,
 'veggie',
 32256,
 'NIL',
 'NIL',
 'pawn',
 12415,
 'NIL',
 'NIL',
 'fruit',
 'NIL',
 'veggie',
 24145,
 'pawn',
 'NIL',
 'NIL']

In [5]: df = pandas.DataFrame({'id':a[::2], 'type':a[1::2]})
 
#      id    type
#0  26235   fruit
#1  26235  veggie
#2  32256     NIL
#3    NIL    pawn
#4  12415     NIL
#5    NIL   fruit
#6    NIL  veggie
#7  24145    pawn
#8    NIL     NIL


In [6]: id_is_nill = df.id=="NIL"

In [7]: left = df.loc[id_is_nill].reset_index()

In [8]: right = df.loc[~id_is_nill].reset_index()

In [9]: mrg = pandas.merge(left, right, on='type').query("type != 'NIL'")

In [10]: mrg
Out[10]: 
   index_x id_x    type  index_y   id_y
0        3  NIL    pawn        7  24145
1        5  NIL   fruit        0  26235
2        6  NIL  veggie        1  26235

In [11]: df.loc[mrg.index_x, 'id'] = mrg.id_y.values

In [12]: df
Out[12]: 
      id    type
0  26235   fruit
1  26235  veggie
2  32256     NIL
3  24145    pawn
4  12415     NIL
5  26235   fruit
6  26235  veggie
7  24145    pawn
8    NIL     NIL
```

Alternative approach based on dictionary query

```
# starting with original dataframe
In [5]: df = pandas.DataFrame({'id':a[::2], 'type':a[1::2]})
 
#      id    type
#0  26235   fruit
#1  26235  veggie
#2  32256     NIL
#3    NIL    pawn
#4  12415     NIL
#5    NIL   fruit
#6    NIL  veggie
#7  24145    pawn
#8    NIL     NIL

In [60]: id_lookup = df[['id', 'type']].query("id!= 'NIL' and type != 'NIL'").set_index('type').to_dict()['id']

In [61]: id_lookup
Out[61]: {'fruit': 26235, 'veggie': 26235, 'pawn': 24145}

In [62]: 

In [67]: df['patched_id'] = [id_lookup[t] if t in id_lookup else i for i,t in zip(df.id, df.type)]

In [68]: df
Out[68]: 
      id    type patched_id
0  26235   fruit      26235
1  26235  veggie      26235
2  32256     NIL      32256
3    NIL    pawn      24145
4  12415     NIL      12415
5    NIL   fruit      26235
6    NIL  veggie      26235
7  24145    pawn      24145
8    NIL     NIL        NIL
```

Comment: the answer works but does not appear to scale for large datasets. Would you recommend looping instead?

Comment: depends on where exactly the slow step is ...

Comment: I added with another approach that might scale better. Another option is to use the original method I posted, but perform the merge on dataframes containing  only the relevant columns (type and id), then use the [dataframe update method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) to combined the results (new id column) with the original, larger dataframe

Comment: your alternative solution scales much better! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do it

create a dictionary of type and id, and then using loc to fill in the missing values

```
d=df[df['id'].ne('NIL')].drop_duplicates(subset=['type']).to_dict()

df.loc[df['id'].eq('NIL'), 'id'] = df['type'].map(d)
df
```

```
id  type
0   26235   fruit
1   26235   veggie
2   32256   NIL
3   24145   pawn
4   12415   NIL
5   26235   fruit
6   26235   veggie
7   24145   pawn
```

Comment: Doesn't work, what could be wrong? Note there are multiple other columns in the dataframe.

Comment: Is dictionary created successfully? Check print(d).  There could be spaces in type so strip that prior to map using df[‘type’].str.strip().map(d)

Comment: Not success, NIL appears to have been replaced with NaN. Any ideas? Note that IDs are not unique, they are repeated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```py
#d = df.loc[(df.id != 'NIL') & (df.type != 'NIL')].set_index('type')['id']
d = df[df!='NIL'].dropna().set_index('type')['id']

df.loc[df.id =='NIL', 'id'] = df.loc[df.id == 'NIL', 'type'].map(d)
```

print(df):

```
     id    type
0  26235   fruit
1  26235  veggie
2  32256     NIL
3  24145    pawn
4  12415     NIL
5  26235   fruit
6  26235  veggie
7  24145    pawn
```

Comment: "InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects" Note: there are other columns in the DF, not sure if that matters though.

Comment: @ngnwoenqwl you probably have 'NIL' in other columns too. Try the updated answer.

Comment: No success, NIL appears to be replaced with NaN